# Is this a correct implementation of a meandice loss function

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

HarDNet was trained to perform semantic segmentation of images. Increase of a meandice implies that the model quality improved.

```py
    def meandice(pred, mask):
        weit = 1 + 5 * torch.abs(F.avg_pool2d(mask, kernel_size=31, stride=1, padding=15) - mask)
        wbce = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, mask, reduce='none')
        wbce = (weit * wbce).sum(dim=(2, 3)) / weit.sum(dim=(2, 3))

        pred = torch.sigmoid(pred)
        inter = ((pred * mask) * weit).sum(dim=(2, 3))
        union = ((pred + mask) * weit).sum(dim=(2, 3))
        wiou = 1 - (inter + 1) / (union - inter + 1)

        return (wbce + wiou).mean()
```

This is the code they are using. But the increase in `wbce` (binary cross entropy) implies that the predictions are getting worse. Same is true for `wiou` which  `1 minus the Intersection over the Union`. The `weit` is a weighting coefficient that increases the loss cost near the boundaries.

Should this function be minimized during the optimization?